# Writing to and reading from file - Java - Not reading what I wrote into file

Tags: java

I'm executing an encryption algorithm and I need your help regarding writing to and reading from a `.xtt` file in Java. As part of the encryption, I basically need to write Base64 encoded bytes into a `.txt` file and read these exact bytes, decode them and use them to execute the decryption process.

I seem to be reading something different compared to what I'm writing into the `.txt` file. Basically when I check the bytearray I'm writing into the file it is reads as `[B@56e5b723` but when I read it of my file it produces `[B@35a8767`.

Here's the outcome as printed in my Java console:

```
***Numbs converted to ByteArray is as follows: [B@56e5b723
Size of NumbsByteArray is: 10

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

-x-x-x-x-x WriteByteArrayToFile(byte[] encoded) HAS STARTED -x-x-x-x-x

6,7,8,9,10 has been received as a byte array in WriteByteArrayToFile(byte[] encoded): [B@56e5b723

6,7,8,9,10 IS TO BE WRITTEN TO THE FILE: /Users/anmonari/Desktop/textfiletwo.txt

bs.write(encoded); HAS BEEN CALLED

-x-x-x-x-x WriteByteArrayToFile(byte[] encoded) HAS ENDED -x-x-x-x-x

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

-x-x-x-x-x ReadByteArray() HAS STARTED -x-x-x-x-x

fileData read as bytes is: [B@35a8767

Size of fileData is: 10

fileDataString when converted to a string using String object is����������

fileDataString when converted to a string using fileDataStringTwo.toString()[B@35a8767

fileDataString.getBytes(); is: [B@2c6f7ce9

-x-x-x-x-x ReadByteArray() HAS ENDED -x-x-x-x-x***
```

Below is my code:

```
package com.writeandreadfromfile;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteAndRead {

    public static void main(String j[]) {

        String Numbs = "6,7,8,9,10";

        byte[] NumbsByteArray = Numbs.getBytes();

        System.out.println("Numbs converted to ByteArray is as follows: " + NumbsByteArray);
        System.out.println("Size of NumbsByteArray is: " + NumbsByteArray.length);

        System.out.println("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

        WriteByteArrayToFile(NumbsByteArray);

        System.out.println("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");

        try {
            ReadByteArrayFromFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Write ByteArray To File
    public static void WriteByteArrayToFile(byte[] NumbsByteArray) {
        System.out.println("\n-x-x-x-x-x WriteByteArrayToFile(byte[] encoded) HAS STARTED -x-x-x-x-x");

        System.out.println("6,7,8,9,10 has been received as a byte array in WriteByteArrayToFile(byte[] encoded): " + NumbsByteArray);

        String fileName = "/Users/anmonari/Desktop/textfiletwo.txt";

        System.out.println("6,7,8,9,10 IS TO BE WRITTEN TO THE FILE: " + fileName);

        BufferedOutputStream bs = null;

        try {

            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
            bs = new BufferedOutputStream(fs);
            bs.write(NumbsByteArray);
            System.out.println("bs.write(encoded); HAS BEEN CALLED");
            bs.close();
            bs = null;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (bs != null) try { bs.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}

        System.out.println("-x-x-x-x-x WriteByteArrayToFile(byte[] encoded) HAS ENDED -x-x-x-x-x");
    }

    // Read ByteArray To File
    public static void ReadByteArrayFromFile() throws IOException {
        // Create FileInputStream and feed it the file name
        System.out.println("-x-x-x-x-x ReadByteArray() HAS STARTED -x-x-x-x-x");

        File file;

        try {
            file = new File("/Users/anmonari/Desktop/textfiletwo.txt");

            // Create the object of DataInputStream
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream((new FileInputStream(file)));

            byte[] fileData = new byte[(int)file.length()];

            System.out.println("fileData read as bytes is from file: "  + fileData);

            System.out.println("Size of fileData is: " + fileData.length);

            //String fileDataString = in.readLine();

            String fileDataString = new String(fileData);
            System.out.println("fileDataString when converted to a string using String object is"  + fileDataString);

            String fileDataStringTwo = fileData.toString();
            System.out.println("fileDataString when converted to a string using fileDataStringTwo.toString()" + fileDataStringTwo);

            fileDataString.getBytes();
            System.out.println("fileDataString.getBytes(); is: "  + fileDataString.getBytes());

            //Close the input stream
            in.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("-x-x-x-x-x ReadByteArray() HAS ENDED -x-x-x-x-x");

    }
}
```

Any assistance regarding how to read from a file the exact byte array you wrote onto a file is appreciated!

Comment: You don't do anything with the input stream `in`. You commented out the line.

Comment: Aside from that, I'm thinking encodings - UTF-8 vs UTF-16 automatic detection may be going on?

Comment: Another tip: when you print `NumbsByteArray`, use `Arrays.toString(NumbsByteArray)`.  What you're printing right now is the memory address, which you don't care about.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, thanks. I've enabled in and used what JB Nizet proposed to read the byte array and I can confirm what's written into the file is what's read into the file i.e. [54, 44, 55, 44, 56, 44, 57, 44, 49, 48].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what Sotirios pointed out (you're not reading from `in`), you're writing the byte array as text, *i.e.* "6,7,8,9,10", but then you're calling `fileDataString.getBytes();`.  That gets the bytes of the string, which (assuming UTF-8) will be `0x36 0x2c 0x37 0x2c 0x38 0x2c 0x39 0x2c 0x31 0x30`.

If your plan is that the file will be text, you need to *parse* the string back into a byte array.  Maybe something like

```
String[] numbers = fileDataString.split();
byte[] bytes = new byte[numbers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(numbers[i]);
}
```

On the other hand, if you just need to save and restore byte arrays, you'll have a simpler time with just an [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html).

Comment: THANKS!!! I've enabled the in and as JB Nizet pointed out I've used System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array)); to my byte array prior to writing into the file whereby I get [54, 44, 55, 44, 56, 44, 57, 44, 49, 48] for my array and the same result after reading from the file. My plan is to use my read output for base64 decoding whereby the encoded result will be the contents read from the .txt file. I don't know if the parsing you proposed is suitable for output in relation to encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You're not printing the contents of the byte arrays. You're outputting their type and hashCode (the result of the `toString()` method on arrays).

To output the contents of a byte array, use

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: H, JB NIZET. Thanks !!! System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array)); works as I'm able to confirm that the byte array prior to being written in the file matches what is read out of the file i.e. [54, 44, 55, 44, 56, 44, 57, 44, 49, 48] is what I'm writing into the file and I'm able to read the same from the file. My plan is to use my read output for base64 decoding whereby the encoded result will be the contents read from the .txt file.

Comment: Hi JB NIZET I also enabled the in before applying your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try bs(fs).flush() which buffered everything which were written out

Comment: Calling `close()` on the stream will flush it.